# Form validation jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to made a simple contact form validaton. I´m newbie in Javascript. I tried many tutorials for newbies, hovever, no one tutorial solved my situation, so I´m trying to made my own JS.

But it have two issues:

1. Form is sent though is empty, although incorrect validation
2. If validation is failed, it should return all errors on same time

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {

    if (validate()) {
        $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"),
        $("#contact-form :input").serializeArray(),

        function (info) {

            $("#f1Err").empty();
            $("#f1Err").html(info);
            $("#f2Err").empty();
            $("#f2Err").html(info);
            $("#f3Err").empty();
            $("#f3Err").html(info);
            $("#f4Err").empty();
            $("#f4Err").html(info);
            clear();
        });

        $("#contact-form").submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
    }

});

function validate() {

    if ($("#f1").val() == "") {
        $("#f1Err").html("Name is requied");
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#f2").val() == "") {
        $("#f2Err").html("E-mail is requied");
        return false;
    }

    var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;

    if (!re.test($("#f2").val())) {
        $("#f2Err").html("Incorrect e-mail format");
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#f3").val() == "") {
        $("#f3Err").html("Message subject is requied");
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#f4").val() == "") {
        $("#f4Err").html("Message is requied");
        return false;
    }

    return (true);
}

function clear() {

    $("#contact-form :input").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form autocomplete="off" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="modules/process.php">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" class="move" name="f1" id="f1" /><span class="error" id="f1Err"></span>

        <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" class="move" name="f2" id="f2" /><span class="error" id="f2Err"></span>

        <label>E-mail</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" class="move" name="f3" id="f3" /><span class="error" id="f3Err"></span>

        <label>Message subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <textarea type="text" class="move" name="f4" id="f4"></textarea><span class="error" id="f4Err"></span>

        <label>Message</label>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.  1. Issue: Form is sent though is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the first click function and the submit functionality, you haven't preventedDefault() to prevent the default method of the submit input you have provided, so you would need to preventDefault() of the event that is  being sent in like so

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (validate()) {
    $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"),
    $("#contact-form :input").serializeArray(),

    function (info) {

        $("#f1Err").empty();
        $("#f1Err").html(info);
        $("#f2Err").empty();
        $("#f2Err").html(info);
        $("#f3Err").empty();
        $("#f3Err").html(info);
        $("#f4Err").empty();
        $("#f4Err").html(info);
        clear();
    });

    $("#contact-form").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });
}

});
```

as the method name shows, its "preventing the default behavior" from running. Next in your validation method, you are returing false after checking a field, so once that one of the validations fails, you are returning. maybe you should return a flag instead so like:

```
function validate() {
      var flag = true;
if ($("#f1").val() == "") {
    $("#f1Err").html("Name is requied");
    flag = false;
}
if ($("#f2").val() == "") {
    $("#f2Err").html("E-mail is requied");
    flag = false;
}

var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;

if (!re.test($("#f2").val())) {
    $("#f2Err").html("Incorrect e-mail format");
    flag = false;
}

if ($("#f3").val() == "") {
    $("#f3Err").html("Message subject is requied");
    flag = false;
}
if ($("#f4").val() == "") {
    $("#f4Err").html("Message is requied");
    flag = false;
}

return flag;
}
```

I think should solve your two biggest issues that you pointed out were wrong. (this is not necessarily the best implementation and variable names, i'll leave you to learn and improve on it)

Comment: Nice improves, thanks. Unfortunately, form is still sent though is empty. In Jsfiddle everthing seems ok. I don´t underestand it.

Comment: @AEA because if the validation is fine, you're still submitting the form?  and then also on the post, you're serializing an array, when the data that is expected is in object form

Comment: I don´t know where is the problem, after 3 hours solving this maybe I will rather use pure PHP based solution. But thanks for help.

Comment: @AEA well good luck then. I think it would be worth it to persue this in your free time to try and debug some issues (notably the serilizeArray, imo) because javascript is a pretty big part of the web, whether you like the language or not. Plus it'll help you get better at programming in general as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/3dnkvtb1](http://jsfiddle.net/3dnkvtb1/). I set errors to false before validating each input, then for each check I set error to true if empty. Make sure to check the console for errors as you go. I added a console.log for each check. Then if no errors, send and clear your form.

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();


        var hasError = false;
        var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;


        if ($("#f1").val() == "") {
            hasError = true;
            $("#f1Err").html("Name is required");
        }
        console.log($("#f1").val());

        if ($("#f2").val() == "") {
            hasError = true;
            $("#f2Err").html("E-mail is required");
        }
        console.log($("#f2").val());

        if (!re.test($("#f2").val())) {
            hasError = true;
            $("#f2Err").html("Incorrect e-mail format");
        }
        console.log($("#f3").val());

        if ($("#f3").val() == "") {
            hasError = true;
            $("#f3Err").html("Message subject is required");
        }
        console.log($("#f3").val());

        if ($("#f4").val() == "") {
            hasError = true;
            $("#f4Err").html("Message is required");
        }
        console.log($("#f4").val());

       if(!hasError){
         console.log('no errors');
         //send your form
         $.ajax({
            url: 'url-here',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            action : 'submit',
            data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                //do something
                clear();
            }
         });
      } else {
         console.log('something is up');
      }


     function clear() {
        $("#contact-form :input").each(function () {
            $(this).val("");
        });
     }

  });
```

Comment: I would like to note, it was fine how AEA left the validation in the function, which is actually better because then its more modular and he can then use the validation anywhere. though it can be even more modular. though what you wrote isn't wrong.